# Remove Session with jquery?

Tags: session, jquery, webforms

is there any way to remove session with jquery?
or i use webmethod to remove session (is this good solution?):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Default.aspx/RemoveSession",
    type: "POST",
    data: {},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

webMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void RemoveSession()
{
    Session.Remove("UserName"); 
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove one variable from the session?

Comment: The session is not accessible to jQuery. You can use ajax calls to server side that set (or unset) session variables.

Comment: If session is based on cookied you can remove them, and it will be like removeing session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sessions are maintained on server and could not removed on client without sending request to server.

You can do it will ajax call at most or use postback to remove the sessions.

Answer (score 1):

If session is based on cookies you can remove them, and it will be like removeing session