# How to destroy session on clicking back button of browser using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

After login, if i click back button of browser then i want to destroy session by directing it to a php page using jquery.

Here is my jquery code which is working fine for mozilla. but not working on chrome.i want browser independent .

Thanks in advance.

```
          <script>
              $(document).ready(function(){ 
                  if (typeof history.pushState === "function") {
                         history.pushState("bbs", null, null);
                         window.onpopstate = function () {
                         history.pushState('newbbs', null, null);
                   };
               $(location).attr('href','backbuttonsessiondeactivation.php');
               }

           });       
         </script>
```

Here is my backbuttonsessiondeactivation.php content:

```
                 <?php
                    session_start();
                    extract($_REQUEST);

                    session_destroy();
                    header("Location:login.php");
                 ?>
```

how could i achieve this??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098802/remove-session-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You could consider making an Ajax call to backbuttonsessiondeactivation.php instead.

```
$.ajax(function() {
    url: "http://yourwebisteurl.com/path/to/backbuttonsessiondeactivation.php",
});
```